# How can I turn down the sensitivity of my volume slider

Tags: sound

I'm on a laptop and I have a touch sensitive volume control slider thing which works in Ubuntu but is way too sensitive, a tiny little stroke and its either at full volume or nothing. Is there a way of changing its sensitivity?

I'm on an hp6715b laptop if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer for *How can I make the volume change in smaller increments?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10525/how-can-i-make-the-volume-change-in-smaller-increments/27029#27029) answers it, and I've used it to good effect on my HP 6710b.

1. Run `gconf-editor` (*Applications > System Tools > Configuration editor* in Ubuntu 10.10)
2. Navigate to `/apps/gnome_settings_daemon`
3. Change the `volume_step` value. Mine was originally 6, 2 works better for me.

Comment: Brilliant. Works a treat. I've been wanting to sort that for ages.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do anything in Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity any more. (Not sure about Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity as I gave up on Unity after a couple of days' trial.)

Comment: Yep I can confirm that.

Comment: Time to join https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/871133