# How do I alter the keyboard volume control to be less sensitive?

Tags: keyboard, volume-control

How do I alter the keyboard volume control to be less sensitive?

I have a Logitech Media Keyboard 600 which has a wheel for volume control. I find the amount the volume changes between 'clicks' is too high. It's set much more for a button press of volume change, not a scrolling wheel.

Thanks,
Noki

Comment: I think this is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/871133

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10525/how-can-i-make-the-volume-change-in-smaller-increments/704733#704733