# Change volume-steps in Ubuntu 18.10? (Gnome Shell)

Tags: sound, gnome-shell

On Ubuntu 18.10, on my laptop (Lenovo W530), there are 2 ways to easily change the volume:

- <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> buttons on the keyboard:
  [image: volume change GIF]
- Scroll wheel Up/Down on the speaker icon with the mouse:
  [image: volume change GIF]

Using the <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> buttons has 17 steps from min to max.

Using the scroll wheel has 50 steps from min to max and I find it too low.

My question is: how do we change either step size?

This may look like a duplicate of [how-can-i-make-the-volume-change-in-smaller-increments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10525/how-can-i-make-the-volume-change-in-smaller-increments) but it's not: this question is about Ubuntu 18.10 running Gnome Shell, not Unity.

Comment: wow! good question! never heard of that paramater so far as i can recall. I wonder is this is somthing we can set via `gsettings`

Comment: it seems `gsettings list-recursively | grep audio` was not it, `gsettings list-recursively | grep sound` either, `gsettings list-recursively | grep volume` gives us a couple interesting entries, though : `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up 'XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down 'XF86AudioLowerVolume'` configuring `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` might be possible. However i think it's very lickely that "sound scrolling" is dirrectly handled by mouse scroll speed. heve you tried this : https://askubuntu.com/a/259628/307184 to confirm it?

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, but note that the target question is *not* specific to any Ubuntu version or desktop environment. It has answers for various Ubuntu version and DE's. This one is about GNOME: https://askubuntu.com/a/1003077/480481