# How to change step of volume in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, lts, volume-control

How can I change volume step in my Ubuntu? I have tried next ways:

- dconf
- gconf
- some scripts

Third way didn't work, but if it would works, it doesn't show current volume value, I think

Comment: No, I have tried everything from this post

Comment: I'm not sure about *everything* mentioned there, but if you can do [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003077/480481) correctly, it would work.

Comment: Shift + UpArrow (which name is X86AudioRaiseVolume in dconf) desn't working, like not working shift + DownArrow (which name is X86AudioLowerVolume in dconf). Maybe I am wrong and these arrows aren't X86AudioRaiseVolume or X86AudioLowerVolume

Comment: Those are **not** up/down arrows; those are dedicated volume-up/volume-down keys in the keyboard (usually paired with some function keys, especially in compact keyboards).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I didn't know, that up/down arrows aren't X86Audio...